# Why doesn't my template parameter pack work?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-argument-deduction

I have been trying to get a templated function to call a set of similar functions to avoid boilerplate.

```
FooA(float a, Widget* w);
FooB(int b, Widget* w);
FooC(int c, Widget* w);
FooD(int d, int e, Widget* w);

template <typename... Args>
static void RunFoo(void (*foo)(Args..., Widget*), Args... args) {
    Widget w
    foo(args, &w);
}
```

I don't understand why this works fine with:

```
float a = 10;
RunFoo(FooA, a);
```

But it fails whenever I try with multiple arguments:

```
int a = 10;
int b = 3;
RunFoo(FooD, a, b);
```

It fails to compile with the error:
"candidate template ignored: failed template argument deduction"

Is this beyond the capabilities of c++ templates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template<class T>struct tag {using type=T;};
template<class Tag>using type_t=typename Tag::type;
template<class T>using block_deduction=type_t<tag<T>>;

template <typename... Args>
static void RunFoo(block_deduction<void(*)(Args...,Widget*)> foo, Args... args) {
  Widget w
  foo(args, &w);
}
```

you cannot deduce like `Args..., Widget*` -- parameter packs must be last in general.

Both cases are "equal" in deduction.  `block_deduction` prevents deduction from occurring on that parameter.  So the other deduction happens, and works.

Note that such deduction is usually a bad idea.  You don't want to deduce one parameter, and generate a function pointer elsewhere.  It is brittle.

This might be better:

```
template <class F, class... Args>
static std::result_of_t<F(Args..., Widget*)> RunFoo(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
  Widget w
  return std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)..., &w);
}
```

if you are passing an overload set in, wrap the overload set up in an overload set object.  `std::result_of_t<?>` is C++14, replace with `typename std::result_of<?>::type` in C++11.